# Why don’t we say “vetein tal lev’racha”?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, shemoneh-esrei, geshem-tal-ruach

According to those who say “*morid hatal*” in the second b’racha of Shemoneh Esrei between Pesach and Sukkos, why don’t they also say *vetein tal lev’racha* in the ninth b’racha (instead of *vetein b’racha*) between Pesach and Sukkos?

If between Sukkos/ December and Pesach we ask for rain in both berachas, why not ask for dew in both berachas?

Comment: You may also like https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82490/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80103/759

Comment: see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/102110/if-dew-is-automatic-why-do-we-have-tefillas-tal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do.

Classical rites that mention dew in the second blessing consistently also request it in the ninth blessing:

- Sefardim say מוריד הטל and וברך שנתנו בטללי רצון
- Italians say מוריד הטל and ותן טל לברכה
- Yemenites say מוריד הטל and וברך את שנותינו בטללי רצון.

Those that don't mention dew in the second blessing also don't request it in the ninth blessing:

- Ashkenazim ([Rama OC 114:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.114.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Tosfot (Taanit 3b) does quote one rabbi who would mention dew in the second blessing all year so as never to accidentally need to go back, though he never indicates he thought that was a traditional practice.

This is all consistent with the Talmud (Taanit 3) that mentioning dew is completely optional. You could choose to mention dew in either, both or neither of those blessings at any time of year and it wouldn't harm your prayer at all.

Comment: Nusach sefard says vetein b’racha and morid hatal...

Comment: for example http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/sidurim/sfarad/hol/shaharit.asp#5

Comment: @Loani maybe some of them do. are you aware there are dozens of versions of "Nusach Sfard" all of which are recent mixtures of various traditional rites? It's not surprising that some of them wound up being 'inconsistent'. That's like why we don't recommend picking all the leniencies from different rabbis: someone who mixes is likely to wind up inconsistent in a way they didn't expect.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but at least some of the “versions” are inconsistent, and those are the versions that I am most familiar with.